# Struct by value in loop

Tags: c

Say I have a function from another api that returns structs by value

```
struct foo{
    int bar;
    bool success;
}

foo getThefoo();
```

What happens in a loop if this function is called eg

```
int foolen = 0;
foo** foos;
do {
    foolen++;
    foos = realloc(foos,sizeof(foo*)*foolen);
    foo myfoo = getThefoo();
    foos[foolen-1]=&myfoo;

}while (/**something*//)
```

Does a new foo struct get allocated on the stack for each iteration?. Or is the initial allocation reused?. I ask because taking a pointer to that structure might be an unexpected value.

`getThefoo` is defined in an external library. So its not trivial to make that return a pointer to a food structure.

Comment: Undefined behavior. Copy the data to heap or it's invalidated when out of scope.

Comment: If the code as shown compiles a C++ compiler was used. It won't compile using a C compiler. (`foo myfoo = ...`, `sizeof(foo*)`). For the code shown to be valid C all those `foo`s need be `struct foo`s.

Comment: @alk Also, there are two semicolons missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work, you're storing the address of a local which will go out of scope, rendering the stored addresses useless.

The proper fix seems to be to not store pointers to `struct foo`s in the array, but just storing them directly:

```
struct foo *foos = NULL;
size_t foolen = 0;

do {
  ++foolen;
  foos = realloc(foos, foolen * sizeof *foos);
  foos[foolen - 1] = getTheFoo();
} while(something something);
```

Of course, the usual caveats apply:

- It's more efficent to call `realloc()` less often, by over-allocating and tracking array length and array allocated space separately.
- `realloc()` can fail, the above loses the old allocation (if any) when that happens.

Note that structures are values and thus fully assignable, so that's what we do.